# Call Json by index?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to return some errors to my jquery method. What is happening is I am doing a post(with a type of "json") and if they get errors I want to display the error back to them. I am doing client side validation but some of these are errors that are like server related(ie the database died or something and that update could not happen).

Anyways there could be a few errors and I want to return them all at one go.

So the only way I know really how is to use Json but I now I get the json object I want to get all the fields out of it. I don't want to call it by their name though since I want to use the same methods for all my methods and each one has different names.

So if I could call it by index there would be alot less typing.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you could use [$.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) to iterate over object properties, for example:

```
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };

jQuery.each(obj, function(key, val) {
      console.log(key,val);
});
```

For objects jQuery [internally](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/tags/1.3.2/src/core.js#671) executes a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) statement, which does not iterate over built-in properties, however you can have problems if the Object.prototype is extended since that extended members will be iterated also.

Is not a common practice to extend the Object.prototype, but to avoid problems you can use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function to ensure that the property exist directly on the object being iterated:

```
for ( var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key,obj[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is nothing more than yet another markup-language to describe complex datastructures. JSON gets parsed into javascript data-structures and can represent objects, arrays or just a string in theoretically unlimited depth.

Without knowing if your JSON structure consists of arrays, objects, or {} constructs it's hard to tell if you can.

However, you could have a look at:

```
var dataObject = {
  key1: "error1",
  key2: "error2"
};

for (var key in dataObject) {
  alert(key + " : " + dataObject[key]);
}
```

Comment: You should be very careful when using this method - http://www.cosmocode.de/en/blog/detman/2006-06/27-json-and-for-each-pitfalls

Comment: Yes, I probably should have mentioned the issue when the prototype has been extended. I've been bitten by that in the past.

Comment: Well I am using json.net library.  It turns it into a string.